# Unix Time Stamp and JavaScript Time; too big!

Tags: php, javascript, time, bignum

I'm using the flot graphing library for jQuery, and it uses javascript time for any time series (to remind, that's milliseconds since Jan 1970. Unix time is *seconds*).

My current code looks like this:

```
foreach($decoded['results'] as $currentResult) {
         if($currentResult['from_user'] == $user) {
             $strippedTexts = $currentResult['created_at'];
             $dates []= strtotime($strippedTexts);
         }
    }
```

This gives me an array of Unix time stamps. I want to prep the data for JavaScript in the loop, but when I try

```
$dates []= 1000*strtotime($strippedTexts);
```

the number is too big and it spits out "[-2147483648]". Do I need to change the "type" of variable allowed to be held in the array to bignum or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of below comment, so you get a response notification: How do you get the variables to the javascript? Javascript can't read PHP variables, so you must be passing it somehow. It shouldn't care whether it's a string or a number at that point. If you can show how you're actually using the $dates array I can have a look at that.

Comment: (not at my work computer) but I am printing the array roughly like: <script type=text/javascript> var data = <?php print($array); ?> </script> , but actually call the variable w/in the script tag using the flot library function. The full program is up at: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,248668.0.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [BCMath Arbitrary Precision functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) if you have them available:

```
$dates[] = bcmul("1000", strtotime($strippedTexts));
```

Or just, you know, append three zeros on the end.

```
$dates[] = strtotime($strippedTexts).'000';
```

In both cases you'll end up with the value being stored as a string, but that shouldn't matter for your usage.

Comment: I tried:

    $strippedTexts = $currentResult['created_at'];
          $bigstring = strtotime($strippedTexts).'000';
    $dates []= settype($bigstring, "float");

And it produces an array of all "1"s. Unfortunately, the javascript library I'm using needs the results as a number, not a string. Any other thoughts?

Comment: How do you get the variables to the javascript? Javascript can't read PHP variables, so you must be passing it somehow. It shouldn't care whether it's a string or a number at that point. If you can show how you're actually using the $dates array I can have a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$dates []= 1000.0*strtotime($strippedTexts);
```

That will turn it into float, which in php can store a bigger number than an int.

Comment: Does each element of an array have it's own variable type then?

Comment: PHP is loosely typed.  I think you can mix any types in an array.

Comment: I'm finally back to my test machine; this still results in the barfing of a large negative number and then the array halts. Gross, barf!

Comment: @Alex, I think you need to try Chad's idea then.  And change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

No solution is required, because there is no problem: have JavaScript do the multiplication.